# Why localization changes only after clicking the date or any other button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used JQuery Datepicker. And added some code to disable dates, after that by default it shows english, after clicking any button or date, it changes into french. Can's see mistakes.. Please any guides..

```
 jQuery(function ($) {
       $.datepicker.regional['fr'] = {clearText: 'Effacer', clearStatus: '',
    closeText: 'Fermer', closeStatus: 'Fermer sans modifier',
    prevText: '&lt;Préc', prevStatus: 'Voir le mois précédent',
    nextText: 'Suiv&gt;', nextStatus: 'Voir le mois suivant',
    currentText: 'Courant', currentStatus: 'Voir le mois courant',
    monthNames: ['Janvier','Février','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin',
    'Juillet','Août','Septembre','Octobre','Novembre','Décembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fév','Mar','Avr','Mai','Jun',
    'Jul','Aoû','Sep','Oct','Nov','Déc'],
    monthStatus: 'Voir un autre mois', yearStatus: 'Voir un autre année',
    weekHeader: 'Sm', weekStatus: '',
    dayNames: ['Dimanche','Lundi','Mardi','Mercredi','Jeudi','Vendredi','Samedi'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dim','Lun','Mar','Mer','Jeu','Ven','Sam'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Di','Lu','Ma','Me','Je','Ve','Sa'],
    dayStatus: 'Utiliser DD comme premier jour de la semaine', dateStatus: 'Choisir le DD, MM d',
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', firstDay: 0, 
    initStatus: 'Choisir la date', isRTL: false};
 $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);

    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: [1, 1],
            showCurrentAtPos: 0,
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
                    if (date.getMonth() == disabledDays[i][0] - 1 && date.getDate() == disabledDays[i][1] && date.getFullYear() == disabledDays[i][2]) {
                       return [true, "ui-state-active", disabledDays[i][3]];
                    }
                }
                return [true, ""];
            },
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
                    if (inst.selectedMonth == disabledDays[i][0] - 1 && inst.selectedDay == ("" + disabledDays[i][1]) && inst.selectedYear == disabledDays[i][2]) {
                        window.open(
                            hrefs[i],
                            '_blank'
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ey6929w3/)

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $.datepicker.regional['fr'] = {clearText: 'Effacer', clearStatus: '',
    closeText: 'Fermer', closeStatus: 'Fermer sans modifier',
    prevText: '&lt;Préc', prevStatus: 'Voir le mois précédent',
    nextText: 'Suiv&gt;', nextStatus: 'Voir le mois suivant',
    currentText: 'Courant', currentStatus: 'Voir le mois courant',
    monthNames: ['Janvier','Février','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin',
    'Juillet','Août','Septembre','Octobre','Novembre','Décembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fév','Mar','Avr','Mai','Jun',
    'Jul','Aoû','Sep','Oct','Nov','Déc'],
    monthStatus: 'Voir un autre mois', yearStatus: 'Voir un autre année',
    weekHeader: 'Sm', weekStatus: '',
    dayNames: ['Dimanche','Lundi','Mardi','Mercredi','Jeudi','Vendredi','Samedi'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dim','Lun','Mar','Mer','Jeu','Ven','Sam'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Di','Lu','Ma','Me','Je','Ve','Sa'],
    dayStatus: 'Utiliser DD comme premier jour de la semaine', dateStatus: 'Choisir le DD, MM d',
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', firstDay: 0, 
    initStatus: 'Choisir la date', isRTL: false};
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);

    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: [1, 1],
        showCurrentAtPos: 0,
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
                if (date.getMonth() == disabledDays[i][0] - 1 && date.getDate() == disabledDays[i][1] && date.getFullYear() == disabledDays[i][2]) {
                    return [true, "ui-state-active", disabledDays[i][3]];
                }
            }
            return [true, ""];
        },
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
                if (inst.selectedMonth == disabledDays[i][0] - 1 && inst.selectedDay == ("" + disabledDays[i][1]) && inst.selectedYear == disabledDays[i][2]) {
                    window.open(
                        hrefs[i],
                        '_blank'
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```